# Javascript editing WFS from GeoServer using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3, geoserver

After reading a very good [tutorial on how to edit WFS with OpenLayers](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-5/), I've tried replicating it but with my own WFS layer from Geoserver. Need some Javascript help finding what's wrong with it.

I managed to load the WFS and my basemap successfully and managed to get the buttons to show up. The buttons appear correctly like in the [working example from that page](http://dbauszus-webmaps.appspot.com/ol3-wfs-t) but, for some reason the geometry data isn't being saved. Every time a user draws something, a new id is created on the table but its associated geometry column is left empty

The bit for posting is:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
featureNS: 'http://geoserver.org/bftchamber',
featureType: 'bft',
srsName: 'EPSG:27700'
});
var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
switch(p) {
case 'insert':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
    break;
case 'update':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
    break;
case 'delete':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
    break;
}
s = new XMLSerializer();
str = s.serializeToString(node);
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: str
    }).done();
}
```

Fiddle with the whole code (apologies if it looks messy, most of it comes from the working example [2](http://dbauszus-webmaps.appspot.com/ol3-wfs-t) )
https://jsfiddle.net/Luffydude/ex06jr1e/6/

The app looks like this:

[image]

Also even though my WFS appears correctly along the river Thames when I load it in QGIS, in my app it appears somewhere else in the ocean even though I specified EPSG 27700 (though this is just a minor annoyance at the moment).

My main problem now is how to make the edit buttons save user edits to the WFS layer?

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo no errors in the console, buttons don't work

Comment: Within the example (http://dbauszus-webmaps.appspot.com/ol3-wfs-t)  you provide buttons work as expected. Now you say your code doesnt work but you dont provide your code. How do you expect us to find what is wrong???? Try to make a fiddle to demontrate your case.

Comment: @pavlos uhh I did provide the code, the fiddle is right at bottom of the post

Comment: when I pressed any button I get `ReferenceError: interaction is not defined
 map.removeInteraction(interaction);`

Comment: @pavlos That is very strange but you might be on to something. I thought the interaction was being defined by the following code in the javascript box `case 'btnSelect':
  interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({`

Comment: There is some kind of error in that piece of your code. Though, sounds logic as `map.removeInteraction(interaction);` is called before initialising the interaction. Your fiddle is a bit of mess. I tried to tidy it a bit up but needs some time which I have not available right now. sorry for that. I would recommend to use firebug is order to solve any firebug errors and then see if you still face problems

Comment: @pavlos I got the buttons working!! Editted the OP and the fiddle. Though now they are not saving, every time I refresh the page the edits don't get saved. Also the existing WFS appears in the incorrect spot

Comment: Is your WFS service publicly accessible? I assume you use a Geoserver backend and the data being in a postgis table. I played around with projected data sets but recommend you try first to set up a dataset in the native EPSG 3857 get the update working before migrating to a projected dataset.

Comment: @DennisBauszus the WFS is private and yes it comes from Geoserver and Postgis. The updated version works, though in Postgis every entry in the geometry column is empty when I try drawing stuff

Comment: I created a new jsfiddle for insert, edit, delete. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/13Lwsfmf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't really looked at OpenLayers in anger for a while and I kind of let slip updating my working examples. I just put together a new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/m2ugapnu/) with simple WFS-T insert for polygons.

I use Geoserver 2.8 in production (2.9 in dev and testing).

Database backend is PostGIS 2.1 in production (2.2 dev).

The fiddle uses OpenLayers 3.16.

A few notes to my setup. I tend to have all geometries in EPSG:3857 and I do not specify the SRS in PostGIS. Haters gonna hate but I simply set my geometry column to geometry. This way I can get lines, points and polygons in the same table. I cannot see the mixed geometry in QGIS but this is a simple test setup. It's important that the geometry field is called geometry. It's probably possible but I could not make this work with the field being called the_geom or geom. In that case a record is inserted but the geometry field is empty as described in the post. I believe this is the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE wfs_geom
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  geometry geometry,
  CONSTRAINT wfs_geom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE wfs_geom
  OWNER TO geoserver;
```

Here is the code bit from the jsfiddle.

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'https://geolytix.net/wfs',
    featureType: 'wfs_geom',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var s = new XMLSerializer();

var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('https://maps.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix.wfs/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'wfs_geom',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                opaque: false,
                attributions: []
            })
        }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1, 51.50]),
        zoom: 13
    })
});

var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

map.addInteraction(interaction);

interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
    $.ajax('https://maps.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix.wfs/wfs', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: s.serializeToString(formatWFS.writeTransaction([e.feature], null, null, formatGML))
    }).done();
});
```

Comment: I would say "GISters gonna hate" and "for good reasons". It's a bad idea not to specify the SRS, because, how can I know what is the SRS of the source data? And how to tell postGIS to get the geometry in another SRS? Also you don't specify the dimensions or the geometry Type what is a bad practice too. Try to render in Geoserver a postGIS layer like that and you'll feel weird behaviours. Also what would be the result of intersect this layer with another? Points, Lines, Polygons? Also i'm afraid if you're indexing your geometry column??

Comment: Of course you can do that and postGIS allows you, but it would be convenient at least, to have Views to separate Points Lines and Polygons for your solution to be "GIS friendly"

Comment: Upvoted becuse you provide a solution for Openlayers to feed a WFS, but I suggest you to advise this way to create geomtry colum is not a good practice.

Comment: I completely agree with all the points in the comments. This is a very simple test setup for use in a jsfiddle and not for a production environment. I mentioned this to allow people to fork the fiddle and put other types of geometry in.

Comment: For that reason I upvoted you!! I wrote just to show how to define geometry column correctly! Anyway you provide a good example! =)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo I'm new to Postgis and OpenLayers but I actually need a GIS friendly solution since the purpose is to use the data for GIS analysis. OpenLayers had a very weird behavior when I specified the SRS. What tweaks would you propose that would still make it work?

Comment: @DennisBauszus I just tried creating a new table with geometry named as geometry but replacing your fiddle with my stuff doesn't work as it fails to post my edits as well. Could it be Geoserver or Postgis rejecting my posts? Also I've drawn a line in QGIS that also shows up in the Postgis table, but it doesn't appear when I run the fiddle

Comment: If a record is inserted but the geometry is empty then it is an issue with the geometry column name. Do you have a constraint on the id? Without a constraint you cannot insert new records via Geoserver. Which is the response of the AJAX call?

Comment: My table statement is CREATE TABLE public.bft2
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  linename character varying(254),
  geometry geometry(LineString,27700),
  CONSTRAINT bft2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) 

so I assume that's the constraint. How can I check the response of the AJAX call?

Comment: on the network tab of the chrome debugger you will see the wfs ajax calls.

Comment: Do try to get this first running with EPSG:3857 and thereafter change to a projected dataset if needed. If you throw to many components into the pot at once you don't know which ones foul up the recipe. By adding bit by bit you know exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: Huh actually I can't even get my WFS to load through the fiddle, probably fiddle doesn't allow non public layers to work

Comment: I'm totally blown away, changing to 3857 made it work. Thank you so much!!